# Object of type 'method' has no len() when define a class

Tags: python, dataframe, pytorch, geometry

### I defined a class

```
class Potsdam_Microgrid_DS1(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root, transform=None, pre_transform=None):
        super().__init__(root, transform, pre_transform)

    #List all processed data 
    def processed_file_names(self):
        return ['data_1.pt', 'data_2.pt', 'data_3.pt']
     
    def len(self):
        return len(self.processed_file_names)

    def get(self, idx):
        data = torch.load(osp.join(self.processed_dir, 'data_{}.pt'.format(idx)))
        return data
```

---

### Then run

```
Dataset_path = 'C:\\Users\\SPSC\\Documents\\Potsdam IMGData\\data'
Data=Potsdam_Microgrid_DS1(Dataset_path)
Data.len()
```

---

### Results

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\3/ipykernel_29288/1760764674.py in <module>
----> 1 Data.len()

~\AppData\Local\Temp\3/ipykernel_29288/3878533142.py in len(self)
      8 
      9     def len(self):
---> 10         return len(self.processed_file_names)
     11 
     12     def get(self, idx):

TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len()
```

---

I have no ideas why.

Comment: `self.processed_file_names` is a method. You need to call it to get the list it returns (i.e. `self.processed_file_names()`)

Comment: Thank you a lot. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`processed_file_names` is a method, so

```
len(self.processed_file_names)
```

is asking for the length of a method. You need to call the method:

```
def len(self):
    return len(self.processed_file_names())
```

Comment: Additionaly, `Data.len()` would either be `Data.__len__()`... or `len(Data)`.

Comment: This solved my problem.